# First day income is 1 dollars . On second day income is 4 dollars. And on third day income is 10 dollars. What is the total income after 30 days?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

First day income is $1$ dollars . On second day income is $4$ dollars. And on third day income is $10$ dollars. What is the total income after $30$ days ?

The answer is given $1335$. But how can I figure a pattern here ?

Is it $$1,1+3,1+3+6 ,1+3+6+10 ?$$

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you given the income for a fourth day? Because otherwise, this is really hard to predict. Note that the consecutive incomes are: $1,4,10$ and their successive differences are $3,6$. There are easily two possible valid sequences - if this is a GP: $3,6,18$ and when it's an AP: $3,6,9$

Comment: Have you specified all details of the question completely?

Comment: @GaurangTandon There is one more (and I think it's actually more obvious and corresponds to what the asked has guessed at): the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers. I've mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, that's good as well :D

Comment: @GaurangTandon Thanks, but none of my guesses at the pattern yield the expected answer (the AP one comes closest). In my view a sequence that just lists the first few terms and expects you to guess at the pattern is nowhere near properly defined. I detest so called "IQ test" questions that pull this sort of stunt as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there are many different possibilities for how the sequence is to be reckoned.

If the sequence is like this: $1, 1 + 3*1, 1+3*1 + 3*2, 1+3*1+ 3*2 + 3*3, ...$

then the $n$th term will be $T_n = 1 + \frac 32n(n-1)$ based on the AP sum, properly adjusted.

If the sequence is like this: $1, 1 + 3*2^0, 1+3*2^0 + 3*2^1, 1+3*2^0 + 3*2^1 + 3*2^2, ...$

then the $n$th term will be $T_n = 1 + 3(2^{n-1} - 1)$, based on the GP sum, properly adjusted.

If (and this possibility hasn't yet been mentioned - but it corresponds to what you guessed in your question text, the sequence is like this: $1, 1+(1+2), 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3), 1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+(1+2+3+4)+...$,

then the $n$th term will be $T_n = \frac 16n(n+1)(n+2)$, a derivation based on the sum of the first $n$ triangular numbers.

The thing to take home from all this is that a sequence must be more rigorously defined before we can work on it.